# shell linux is it possible to treat variable assignation contained into a string?

Tags: linux, string, shell, variables

I wonder if it’s possible in shell to use variable declared into a string ?
I dont know how to be explicit so here is my problem :

I use raspi-gpio for drive gpio, and i want to know states of one GPIO example :
raspi-gpio get 21

return a string :
GPIO 21: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT

Into this string there is level=0; fsel=0 and func=INPUT that are like variable declaration for shell.

My question :
Is it possible with minimum line to treat this 3 declarations as variable, for direct use :
if $level == 0 then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming command `raspi-gpio get 21` returns `GPIO 21: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT`

We can delete unneeded `GPIO 21:` in front by "splitting" it from colon (:) character.

Then pipe the output to next command to replace space with newline.

So we have this command:

```
GPIO_OUTPUT=`raspi-gpio get 21`
MYCMD=`echo $GPIO_OUTPUT | cut -d':' -f2 | tr ' ' '\n'`
```

output of `echo -e "$MYCMD"` would be:

```
level=0
fsel=0
func=INPUT
```

This already looks like a valid bash variable assignment, so we can just `source` it:

```
source <(echo -e $MYCMD)
```

Complete code:

```
GPIO_OUTPUT=`raspi-gpio get 21`
MYCMD=`echo $GPIO_OUTPUT | cut -d':' -f2 | tr ' ' '\n'`
source <(echo -e $MYCMD)
if [ $level -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo "level is zero"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, source is exactly what i was seeking for.
Very usefull detailled answer, you have done a lot ^^.